# Spectrum of a compact operator

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, compact-operators

If the spectrum of a compact operator is finite, I don't understand why $0$ has to be a member. I have proved that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is only a finite number of eigenvectors which have eigenvalues $x$ satisfying $|x|>\epsilon$. I can see that when the spectrum is countable, the sequence of eigenvalue tends to zero so since the spectrum is closed, $0$ is a member but don't see why when the spectrum is finite. 
Also, since every operator on a finite dimensional space is compact, am I right in thinking this results is only valid for infinite dimensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed only true in infinite dimensions.

Suppose your compact operator $A$ has finite spectrum.  Then there are only finitely many eigenvectors with nonzero eigenvalue.  Let $F$ be the subspace spanned by those eigenvectors and let $E$ be its orthogonal complement.  Since $F$ is finite dimensional, $E$ is infinite dimensional, and in particular $E \ne 0$.  The restriction of $A$ to $E$ is another compact operator.  What are its eigenvalues?

Comment: Well, if $x$ is an eigenvector of the restriction, with eigenvalue $\alpha$, we have that $<Tx,y>=\alpha<x,y>=0$ for any eigenvector $y$ of A. So Tx is in the orthogonal complement. Hmm don't know where to go from there.

Comment: @user108605: (I adjusted my notation.)  Any eigenvector $x$ of the restriction $A|_E$ is also an eigenvector of $A$, with the same eigenvalue.  If that eigenvalue is not zero, then $x$ is simultaneously in $E$ and $F$...

Comment: Why must $A|_E$ has an eigenvalue?

Comment: @C.Ding: Good point, I think something is wrong with this answer.  Unfortunately I have no time to look at it right now.

Answer (score 10):

If $0$ is not in the spectrum of $A$, then $A$ is invertible with inverse $B$. Since the product of compact operators is compact, the identity $I = AB$ is compact. But this is impossible if $A$ acts on an infinite-dimensional Banach/Hilbert space, because the closed unit ball is not compact.

Comment: @ChrisJudge Firstly, $B$ is bounded. This follows from the Open Mapping theorem. Then given a bounded sequence $\{x_{n}\}$, $\{Bx_{n}\}$ is also bounded. By the compactness of $A$, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ s.t. $\{x_{n_{k}}\} = \{ABx_{n_{k}}\}$ converges. By the continuity of $B$, $\{Bx_{n_{k}}\}$ also converges. This shows that $B$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and suppose that $T : X\rightarrow X$ is linear. Then the following are true:

1. If $X$ is finite-dimensional, then $T$ is compact, regardless of whether or not $0 \in \sigma(T)$.
2. If $X$ is infinite-dimensional and $T$ is compact, then $0 \in \sigma(T)$.

Comment: Could you quote a reference for this fact? Would like to read more about it!

Comment: A compact operator maps bounded sequences to ones with convergent subsequences. If $X$ is finite-dimensional, then $T$ is bounded, which means it mans bounded sequences to bounded sequences, and bounded sequences in finite-dimensional spaces have convergent subsequences. For (2), you cannot an invertible $T$ on an infinite-dimensional Banach space, because  every bounded sequence in $X$ may not converge, but every bounded sequence is the image of a bounded seqeuence if $T$ is bicontinuous.